# Чи можна викорістовувати "Як правило" саме в контексті представленого речення?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

Я не певна, чи за змістом підійде "зазвичай", тому використала "як правило". Чи не є це росіянізмом?
"Як правило ми спостерігаємо напади агресії лише після дії зовнішніх подразників" 
Словосполучення наче є, іначе росіянізм. Чи допустимо його вживання і наведеному реченні.

Comment: Дублікат до [«Чи є помилкою вживання „як правило“?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2987).

Comment: Перечитала. Допоможіть розібратись з моїм випадком, вказано що наче є, але наче росіянізм. Чи можу яв само своєму реченнівикористовувати його?Чи ні?

Comment: В таких випадках важко дійти однозначного висновку: хтось завжди казатиме «росіянізм», а хтось — «завжди так казали». Особисто я б у випадку «як правило» (а не інших спірних випадків) **старався уникати його** — адже існує безліч альтернатив: «здебільшого», «у переважній більшості випадків», «як звичайно», «як водиться», «як заведено», «зазвичай», «здебільшого», «переважно» — і головне: зазвичай, коли кажуть «як правило», мають на увазі ніяке не правило, а просто більшість випадків (тобто слово «правило» тут нелогічно). Але це лише моя особиста неавторитетна думка.

Comment: Дякую, відповідь була коректна і я вдало його замінила.